# Invalid Hook Call when using an async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, solidity, react-dom

I'm trying to build a simple dApp to interact with Solidity Smart contract. I'm trying to get familiar with the hook feature, but I really can't understand what is wrong with this.

```
function UseAsyncHook(){
  const [auctions, setAuctions] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() =>{
    async function fetchActives(){
      try{
        const auct_list = await Auctionscm.getActiveAuctions();
        setAuctions(
          auct_list.items.map(item =>{
            console.log(item[0]);
            return item[0];
          })
        );
      }catch (error){
        console.log("error")
      }
    }
    fetchActives();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        {auctions.map((auction) =>{
            return(
            <ul>
                <li>{auction[0]}</li>
                <li>{}</li>
                <li>{}</li>
            </ul>);})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course AuctionsCm is the reference to the contract, and getAuctions is a method in the contract.
Can you please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
I think I can exclude the typical "two versions on React Dom" problem, since this, in another function (App) works:

```
const connectWallet = async () => {
    const [selectedAddress] = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts", // get the currently connected address
    });
    setSelectedAddress(selectedAddress);
    
    await window.ethereum.enable()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);


  };
  
  // we want to connect the wallet after page loads
  useEffect(() => {
    connectWallet()
  }, [])
```

I've tried multiple fixes for async functions and hooks. I've tried to put this function in another file, exporting it with `export defualt UseAsyncHook` and importing it into the main js, then using it as a jsx `<UseAsyncHook />`, in the return part of my main. Nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the expected result/behaviour? What is the result/behaviour that you are getting? Please elaborate on what is the error using the current setup. Do you get any errors and if so what kind of error output do you get?

Comment: That's not a custom hook. It's basically component...